# Firestore query based on parent document fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have the following structure in Firestore:
[image]

Is there a way I can query (using the JS API) for a list of reviews from orders whose `shopId` is a specific value? Or am I required to add the `shopId` to the review document, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can get all orders of a specific shop, by querying like this:

```
var ordersRef = db.collection("orders");
var query = ordersRef.where("shopId", "==", "someId");
```

To get the corresponding reviews, you have to create a new reference that points to the `review` subcollection and read all reviews, a case in which there is no need to add the shopId as property within the review document.

If you wanted to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), to get all reviews of a specific shop, then you would have needed that:

```
var reviews = db.collectionGroup("review").where("shopId", "==", "someId");
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to use the collection group query, like you showed in the the last part, but was wondering if there is a way to apply the where clause to the shopId of the parent document. Looks like I'll add shopId to reviews too.

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to add in the "review" document too.